# How to install newest Pulseaudio on ubutu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am trying to install the newest Pulseaudio. I found this guide but I am failed immediately on the first step:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/PulseAudioFromGit/

When I cloned repository and run build command I got following error:

```
Found CMake: /snap/bin/cmake (3.20.4)
Run-time dependency tdb found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:514:2: ERROR: Dependency "tdb" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

Can you help me to fix it or tell me if there is simpler way how to install newest version of PA? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it already installed?  If so, what is it exactly that you need from the version you are trying to install that is not working with the version that is provided in Ubuntu's repositories?  Unless there is some feature or bugfix that you absolutely must have, it's better to stick with the software that's in repos.

Comment: @Nmath yes it is, but version 13.99.1, I need never 14 version due to bugs as you said

Comment: Which bugs? And are you sure that the new version fixes those bugs?

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Download/) from the developers of PulseAudio as it pertains to downloading and installing it from source.  Notably, there is the following warning: **"Typically PulseAudio would be provided by your OS distribution. As PulseAudio forms part of what is typically preferred to as the plumbing layer of Linux userspace, it is a non-trivial job to integrate it fully to form a complete system. This is why we strongly encourage you to go via your distribution whenever possible."**

Answer (score 2):

To resolve dependency tdb, use:

```
sudo apt install libtdb-dev
```

You might also need:

```
sudo apt install libsndfile1-dev check
```